# Using Scrapy to extract data from Detail Pages

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl telephone numbers of agencies from this site:

List View
http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/

Detail View
http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/b-personal-management/

The phone number is hidden in the detail page.

So is it possible to go through websites with url like the detail view url above and crawl phone numbers?

My attempt at this code was:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class AgencyItem(Item):
    Phone = Field()

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from agentquery.items import AgencyItem


class AgencySpider(CrawlSpider):
   name = "agency"
   allowed_domains = ["authoradvance.com"]
   start_urls = ["http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/"]
   rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'agencies/*$']), callback='parse_item'),)

   def parse_item(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select("//div[@class='section-content']")
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = AgencyItem()
           item['Phone'] = site.select('div[@class="phone"]/text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return(items)
```

Then I ran "scrapy crawl agency -o items.csv -t csv"
and the result crawled 0 pages.

What's wrong? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you want to check out by yourself what part of the code is failing, you can use something like the python debugger pdb (http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) which allows you to stop your code's execution at any arbitrary point. This way you can easily find out if the regex is the problem and refine your question  accordingly which will make it easier to answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is only one link on the page which satisfies your regex (`agencies/*$`):

```
stav@maia:~$ scrapy shell http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/
2013-04-24 13:14:13-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.17.0 started (bot: scrapybot)

>>> SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'agencies/*$']).extract_links(response)
[Link(url='http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies', text=u'Agencies', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

which is just a link to iteself, and it has no div with a `section-content` class:

```
>>> fetch('http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies')
2013-04-24 13:15:22-0500 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies> (referer: None)

>>> hxs.select("//div[@class='section-content']")
[]
```

therefore your loop does not iterate and `items` never gets appended.

So change you regex to `/agencies/.+`

```
>>> len(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'/agencies/.+']).extract_links(response))
20

>>> fetch('http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/agency-group')
2013-04-24 13:25:02-0500 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.authoradvance.com/agencies/agency-group> (referer: None)

>>> hxs.select("//div[@class='section-content']")
[<HtmlXPathSelector xpath="//div[@class='section-content']" data=u'<div
class="section-content">\n\t      <di'>, <HtmlXPathSelector xpath="//div
[@class='section-content']" data=u'<div class="section-content"><div class='>]
```